# XMLHttpRequest Works In FireFox, Not Safari

Tags: php, javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have an account database on my Mac that uses HTML, Javascript & PHP to delete an account after I click the delete button.  It works every time in FireFox and fails every time in Safari (fail meaning the delete request is completely ignored).

Essentially, this is what my code is doing...

1. Button `onclick` inside a Form calls a js func `verifyDelete()` asking me to verify my choice to delete
2. Next, the `onsubmit` from same form calls a js func `delAccount()`
3. Finally, `delAccount()` uses `XMLHttpRequest` to call a php page to delete the
   account

I got the idea of using the `XMLHttpRequest` from looking at AJAX.  I didn't need all the ReadyState, Response, etc. that AJAX uses so I just used what I needed.  Is it 'legal' to do what I did inside the `delAccount()` function?  Maybe that's why Safari is failing?

Any help is appreciated, here's my code...

FILE - View.php

```
<?php
    // some code
?>
        <form method="get" onsubmit="return delAccount('<?php echo $acctNum; ?>')">
            <input type="hidden" name="acctName" value="Blah” />
            <button onclick="return verifyDelete()" >Delete</button>
        </form>
<?php
    // some code
?>
```

FILE - common.js

```
function verifyDelete() {
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this?\r\n\n" +
        "A)  'Cancel' delete request\r\n" +
        "B)  'OK', delete\r\n");
    if (r == false) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function delAccount (acctNum) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        var xmlDelete = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlDelete.open("GET", "delAcct.php?q=" + acctNum, true);
    xmlDelete.send(null);
    return false;
}
```

FILE - delAcct.php

```
<?php
    // code to delete account
?>
```

Comment: why arnt you using some javascript library like jQuery? these libraries are built keeping these crossbrowsers issues in mind and also makes your javascript code easy to write and manage.--btw do you see any javascript error in your safari? try to alert acctNum in your delAccount method and see

Comment: I was told that it's better to get familiar with javascript before  learning jquery. Is that not the case?

Comment: I've used alerts all over the place and haven't found anything that it's not supposed to be doing - including traversing the `if` statement so I know the php is being called.

Comment: for things like this i would suggest using some kind of javascript library which will make your life easy.

Comment: so do you see proper acctNum in your delAccount method when u alert in safari?

Comment: Yes, I just now put 3 alerts in the `deleteAccount()` function and they all gave me the appropriate number.  I did the the same thing in FireFox with the same acount and it gave me the same 3 alerts - except the account was actually deleted.

Comment: I got it to work - but not how I want.  If I eliminate the call to `verifyDelete()`, the account is deleted.  It doesn't matter if I assign the `deleteAccount()` to `submit` or `onclick`, it works every time.  Could it maybe be a timing issue?

Comment: People who tell you to go familiar with javascript are right. But javascript as a langage, not the nightmare of crossbrowser development, this won't help you at all. Do some algorithm to learn the first part, when you come to play with DOM or AJAX take JQuery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I overlooked something.  I just needed to swap `true` with `false` for the `XMLHttpRequest`...

```
xmlDelete.open("GET", "delAcct.php?q=" + acctNum, false);
```

I get that it makes the event synchronous, but i don't really know why this work and the other didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You did not cancel the sending of the form, so it may happen that the form get's submitted(what will unload the current page), before the AJAX-request has been sended.

Modify the call of `delAccount()`:

```
<form method="get" onsubmit="return delAccount('<?php echo $acctNum; ?>')">
```

and add this to the end of `delAccount()`

```
return false;
```

...what will avoid the sending of the form

What else: When using GET, the send-method requires `null` as argument

Comment: I added the return `false;` after `xmlDelete.send();` and added null for the send argument, but it still didn't work. I think you're on the right track though, I had just told Kishore that I was able to get it to 'delete' by eliminating the `verifyDelete()` function.  However, I need the "Are you sure?" alert so it's not a fix, it's just that I got it to delete.  Maybe a timing issue?

Comment: Did you also update the call of delAccount inside the form (the  **return** is very important)?

Comment: The fix for this issues was changing true to false on the `xmlDelete.open()` request.  I added the return to this question and my code as you've suggested though, thanks for all the input; my codes more accurate and complete now!